# Como listar registros con run que comiencen con 100

Tags: php, sql

Hola buenas tardes espero que me puedan ayudar nuevamente.

tengo el siguiente caso, en mi pagina tengo que agregar la función de listar solo los registros que comiencen con el run 100. Pero no se como realizar la consulta

Adjunto un ejemplo de la tabla con los valores que necesito que se muestren.

[image: TABLA]

Espero me entiendan, quedo atento a sus comentarios, de antemano GRACIAS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con SQL así, usando LIKE, el operador % actua de comodin de todo lo que viene despues de 100

```
select * from tabla where run like '100%';
```

Comment: ronpy TE AGRADEZCO ME SIRVIÓ DE MARAVILLA.